# How to build a project in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The problem is that the image(logo) and text are not appearing in /dist/index.html. When I do npm run build, I get: Images and other types of assets omitted.

I found some answer in stack overflow according to which I tried importing the image file in App.vue. And also alter package.json file.

Some code is:
I imported image in App.vue as:

```
import './assets/logo.png';
```

I modified the package.json file to:

```
"build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name index src/App.vue"
```

I expected to see the vuetify logo and the text after clicking the index.html file in dist folder after running npm run build. But the actual result is that the index.html file is empty.